# Group permissions in postgreSQL not inheriting to table level

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, role

I am moving to a group role from a lot of individual users and have one table that needs to have permissions `SELECT`, `INSERT` only.

Lets say I have:

```
user1
user2
newgroup
```

Both of the users are in the group and both users have INHERIT as well as the Group has INHERIT on it.

I have added

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA testschema TO newgroup;
GRANT user1 to newgroup;
GRANT user2 to newgroup;
```

as well as

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON testschema.testtable TO newgroup;
```

When I log in as one of the new users, I do not have permission to that table(ex: testschema.testtable)

I look at the PSQL \z and see for that table newgroup has ar permissions.

I am getting permission denied for relation testschema.testtable.  I do not want to create more of a mess by individually putting permissions on the table (it works if I do that currently).

Comment: There is a mismatch in your code: `randomschema` vs. `id.testtable`. You need to provide the *verbatim* code you were using and your version of Postgres or we might not be able to help you. (`users are in the group` - how exactly?) Also comment on the arbitrary capitalization of your role names.

Comment: I am on 9.4 and the schema already exists and the table is going to be a new table.  I also have an existing schema and an existing table that this has to work for also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple test:

```
postgres=# create schema foo;
CREATE SCHEMA
postgres=# create table foo.t(x int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create role foomaster nosuperuser nologin inherit;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create role fooslave password '111' login inherit in role foomaster;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# grant usage on schema foo to foomaster;
GRANT
postgres=# set role fooslave;
SET
postgres=> select * from foo.t;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t
postgres=> set role postgres;
SET
postgres=# grant select on foo.t to foomaster;
GRANT
postgres=# set role fooslave;
SET
postgres=> select * from foo.t;
 x 
---
(0 rows)
```

It seems that you are doing something wrong.

**Upd:** About newely created table:

```
postgres=> set role postgres;
SET
postgres=# create table foo.tt(xx int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# set role fooslave;
SET
postgres=> select * from foo.tt;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation tt
postgres=> set role postgres;
SET
postgres=# grant select on foo.tt to foomaster;
GRANT
postgres=# set role fooslave;
SET
postgres=> select * from  foo.tt;
 xx 
----
(0 rows)
```

PPS: Hope that my investigations was helpful at least for somebody.

Comment: that worked, apparently I was forgetting to put 'inherit in role foomaster' when creating the user, so it wasn't inheriting things down on that group role, in your example.  I dropped the new user and created it with the following:

CREATE ROLE user1 LOGIN
  PASSWORD '123'
  INHERIT IN ROLE newgroup;